# Vocabulary: "Well Bid" and "Fading" Meaning?

Tags: volatility, trading

I think it is important quants understand what traders are talking about. With that, what does it mean:

- "vol is well bid"
- "fade the trade"

?

Comment: "well bid" = lots of bidders i.e. lots of buyers, pushing price up. "fade the trade" = do the opposite, e.g. "I always fade Warren Buffet's trades" = I always do the opposite, sell what he buys and buy what he sells.

Answer (score 1):

"vol is well bid" - lots of buyers options with high vega (price sensitivity to implied volatility), such as long dated options

"fade the trade" - means the person doesn't believe it's a good trade to get in on.  Maybe a temporary spike due to some institutional buying.

Comment: I'd say 'vol is well bid' could refer to short or long-dated options, i.e. does not imply only lots of buyers of vega (could also be gamma buyers). And on fade, it implies - as @noob2 said - take the other side, not just "doesn't believe it's a good trade"